# HTML5 Audio element

Tags: php, javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I want to play from dynamic link for MP3

I am using this code to send mp3 instead of direct link :

PHP Side :

```
$filename = "jadi.mp3";
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";
if (is_file($filename)) {

    header("Content-Type: {$mime_type}");
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename = jadi.mp3");
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    $fd = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (!feof($fd)) {
        echo fread($fd, 1024 * 200);
    }
    fclose($fd);
    exit();
}
```

HMLL side :

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="http://localhost/music.php" type="audio/mpeg"  preload="auto">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

But the Browser can not play that , I have no problem with WAV file , but for mp3 , it does not work

there is no problem if I use direct link instead of php script , so my browser can support MP3

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the browser you're testing in supports `mp3`? Firefox, if I recall correctly, can play `MP3` audio only on Windows with Firefox 21+.

Comment: I use chrome , it can play mp3 sure

Comment: A live example would be much easier to debug. I can't see anything that stands out as incorrect right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you run PHP script alone your browser should be able to download the MP3 file immediately.

if this is not working then there is a some problem in ur PHP Script.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be specifying a single `Content-Type` in your PHP. You can't just send a comma delimited list AFAIK.